# Unicode key for Python dictionary in Python C API

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, unicode, python-c-api

I am using Python C API to connect to my python v2.7.2

As the title suggests, I am looking to use unicode string as key in my dictionary. 
I am aware that we can use unicode string as key in python dictionary.
But how is that possible through Python C API.

```
int PyDict_SetItemString(PyObject *p, const char *key, PyObject *val)
```

we have the above for using the ascii values. Is there any way for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you have asked 7 questions, but have not marked an accepted answer for any of them. If you ask a question, and someone sufficiently answers your question, then you should click the check-mark outline on the left side of the answer to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

[`int PyDict_SetItem(PyObject *p, PyObject *key, PyObject *val)`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/dict.html?highlight=pydict#c.PyDict_SetItem)

and pass in a:

[`PyObject *PyUnicode_FromString(const char *u)`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html?highlight=pyunicode#c.PyUnicode_FromString)

as the `key`

Comment: So when i use `PyObject* PyDict_GetItem(PyObject *p, PyObject *key)` it will retrieve the same key as added above?

Comment: It will retrieve the same value as set above.